# SQLITE - insert question

Tags: sqlite

I've got a list of items in a certain table and I want to have another table with an ID from the first table and another constant values in other columns.

I've got the following query:

```
INSERT INTO table02(item_id, status, card_status) VALUES( (SELECT item_id FROM table01), -1, 10);
```

But it works only for the first row.

How can I make it work for all rows? I need to copy all IDs from table01 and assign to them values -1 and 10 in other columns.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table02 (item_id, status, card_status) SELECT item_id, -1, 10 FROM table01;
```

Answer (score 3):

In ANSI SQL it would be:

```
INSERT INTO table02(item_id, status, card_status)
SELECT item_id, status, card_status FROM table01;
```

where status and card_status are your hard coded values.

...so I guess that would work here too.

Answer (score 3):

I would create `table02` with defaults and then insert only the `item_id` from `table01`.

```
CREATE TABLE table02 ( item_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                       status INTEGER DEFAULT -1,
                       card_status INTEGER DEFAULT 10);
INSERT INTO table02 (item_id) SELECT item_id FROM table01;
```